# If I change the UID of the user I SSH into the machine as, are there going to be problems?

Tags: ssh

A remote machine has a user that I SSH to. I then am that user. A key exists for this user, no password login.

Suppose I were to change the UID/GID of said user, will this cause problems logging in via SSH? Will the key still work?

Googling for this only yields result on how to set up an SSH key or how to change a UID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your public key lives on that user's home directory at remote machine, there will be no issue and your key will work fine, even if you change username or your user's home directory.

So you can still login and work as you are doing it right now.

However if you are using `sshfs` to mount a directory from remote machine on your local system, the remote user ID should match your local's one, otherwise you might experience permission problems on that mount point.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Google really wasn't being helpful.